# How to not decoding Path windowd to escape backslashes

Tags: php

I have to send data to a webservice with a cURL request in POST.
I have a problem because the system automatically converts part of this path to a special character.

My path is `"\\hdone\DDD\CP0359T6\PP26\20210819T144131Z"` 
When I want to escape backslashes with the str_replace method, here is the returned path

```
$string = str_replace("\\","\\\\","\\hdone\DDD\CP0359T6\PP26\20210819T144131Z");
echo $string;
```

Output:
`\\hdone\\DDD\\CP0359T6\\PP26�10819T144131Z`

The system interprets the code \ 202 and convert it to a special character �
Can someone tell me how to avoid interpreting this code "\202", to get the correct url ?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is in your _input_ data already. `echo "\\hdone\DDD\CP0359T6\PP26\20210819T144131Z";` would have gotten you the same character already. You need to escape _that_ backslash, if you actually want to write this value in code.

Comment: I can not escape the character upstream because the data will be sent via an external API. I would like myself to treat the problem in my code to be sure that will happen well.

Comment: What you are saying makes little sense. The only reason you are having this problem with what you have shown above, is because it is _code_. While parsing this, the PHP interpreter will interpret `\202` as an octal character reference (because it matches the regex pattern `\[0-7]{1,3}`, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) - but if you are getting this from an external API _as data_, then that step of interpreting such sequences should not even apply in the first place.